# how to get setInterval work without waiting for it to fetch the results?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using the javascript's `$.get()` function in my ASP .NET application, to get some data from another page and I set this *recieved* data into one of my label's text.

I also set this into a `setInterval()` function to check continuously for new data. But the ***problem*** is : Everytime I load a new page, the script calls the `$.get()` function and there is nothing for `3 seconds` , which i found not pleasing as from a Client end perspective.

Is there some way where-in I can set the value into the label before hand , and then auto-refresh in the background to check for new values?

Here is the script I have written :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function myFunction() {

            $.get("AjaxServicesNoty.aspx", function (data) {

                var recievedCount = data;
                var existingCount = $("lblEventCount").text();


                if (existingCount == "") {
                    $(".lblEventCount").html(recievedCount);
                    $(".lblAcceptedCount").html(recievedCount);

                }

                else if (parseInt(recievedCount) > parseInt(existingCount)) {
                    $(".lblEventCount").html(recievedCount);
                    $(".lblAcceptedCount").html(recievedCount);

                }
                else {
                    $(".lblEventCount").html(existingCount);
                    $(".lblAcceptedCount").html(existingCount);
                }

            });

                }

            setInterval(myFunction,3000);
        </script>
```

Comment: Just call myFunction() when you load your page.

Comment: before the function begins ? i should call it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your function to be executed after the page load, you simply need to invoke it like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
});
```

It will be executed only once but note that it may overlap with the setInterval call if the they are executed asynchronousy (they are by default).

Comment: Will simply calling the function as `myFunction()` on the first line of the script, instead of calling it in inside the `$(document).ready()`  cause any difference ??

Comment: yes since you are updating the page (DOM) after you get ajax response, the page needs to be loaded. Ideally page loading will be faster than ajax call but to be on safe side invoke your function in document ready.

Comment: @gp. : I notice here that , calling the function directly in the first line of script is faster instead of calling it in `$(document).ready()` . Is that delay because of the time taken in DOM generation?